# How to assign a piped output as a variable while pipe is continuous

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, zsh

I want to update the download status at every 5 second of a downloading file to my telegram bot. Also here I'm using bash.

```
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))"
```

This thing derive me download percentage after each 5 seconds. I want to use this download percentage for my bot to update it regularly. I tried these

```
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" | { read text; curl -s "https://api.legram.org/bot${tg_token}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED-${text}&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"; }
```

Try 2

```
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | text=$(grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))") | curl -s "https://api.legram.org/bot${tg_token}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED-${text}%&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"; }
```

But none works. Then for testing I tried this

```
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" | { read text; echo "$text"; }
```

I just got one output at last(which might be the first download %), unlike what it should be. Can anyone get me the working code.

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh if you're using bash?

Comment: Commands are going be same ig. Also was curious to know the answer. I Apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only run `read` (and then updates the status) once, so it reads a single line (and updates the status once). You need a loop, so it'll repeat the `read`+update process over & over. You can use a `while` loop to do this. If it should exit when there's no more input to process, make `read` the `while` condition:

```
aria2c $url --summary-interval=5 2>&1 |
    tee output.log |
    grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))" |
    while read text; do
        curl -s "https://api.legram.org/bot${tg_token}/editMessageText" --data "message_id=${msg_id}&text=DOWNLOADED-${text}&chat_id=${ch_id}&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True"
    done
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is still not working, Like it is giving the output of before while statement, in other terms it's don't look like it reaches the loop statement. To prove this I used ```while read text; do echo "downloaded - $text" done``` (sorry for orientation). It gives the output which I use to get at grep statement.

Comment: So in short it is never reaching curl statement or even read statement. Can you try once with your terminal and tell ?

Comment: I don't have `aria2c` so I can't fully test it, but it worked using `echo "55.3%"` instead, and it worked (except you need a `;` or line break before the `done`). Are you missing the `|` between the `grep` command and the `while read`?

Comment: I just copy pasted your's code for confirmation. Can u use wget ? It works same. Also I will use line breaker and try, before done.

Comment: I don't see a `--summary-interval` option for `wget`. Does `echo "this is a test" | while read text; do echo "downloaded - $text"; done` work?

Comment: Actually I haven't put that line breaker after "$text", will use this time and tell.

Comment: Okay I'm not getting output line be line, but getting whole as once.

Comment: You might be running into buffering; try adding the `--line-buffered` option to `grep`.

Comment: Okay Thanks it's working finally but I'm having one new problem, like it's getting updated every second due to which telegram blocks editing message for 30 seconds. Any hacks for it?

Comment: Not for that one, sorry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help btw.